# Visual basic turning array integers (x) into x amount of a single character

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio, integer

I have been tasked to create a Visual Basic console script that asks the user 5 times in a row to input a number into an array (sales figures in thousands), Then you display these results as a sort of tally chart.

For example for the data:   sales(10,7,12,5,15)
The output would be

```
2008:++++++++++

2009:+++++++

2010:++++++++++++

2011:+++++

2012:+++++++++++++++
```

So far for the code I have:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim sales(4) As Integer
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim year As Integer


    For index = 0 To 4
        Console.Write("Enter your sales numbers (in thousands): ")
        sales(index) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next

    year = 2007

    For index = 0 To 4
        year = (year + 1)
```

---NOT SURE ABOUT CODE HERE---

```
        Console.WriteLine(year & ": " & ????????)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

I am just unsure on how to change the integer value from within the array into a certain number of a single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For Each i As Integer In Sales
    Console.WriteLine(New String("+"c, i))
Next i
```

Comment: Why not just  New String("+"c, i)  ??

Comment: Because I always forget about that constructor overload ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't adding a for to display several times the "-" be sufficient?

Like that:

```
For index = 0 To 4
    year = (year + 1)
    Console.Write(year & ": ")

    ' Display as much "-" as there are sales
    For s = 1 to sales(index)
        Console.Write("-")
    Next s

    Console.WriteLine("") 'Next line
Next index
```

Comment: This still provides me with 1 extra, say I entered had  sales(3,2,3,4,3) the out put is showing 4,3,4,5,4

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I began the for..next at s = 0
I should have written "For s = 1 to sales(index)" instead

Comment: If this problem is solved, you should click on the check next to the answer that helped you solve it to accept the answer.